# Perl greedy regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following string:

`$foo = "'fdsfdsf', 'fsdfdsfdsfdsfds fdsf sdfd f sfs', 'fsdfsdfsd f' fdfsdfdsfdsfsf";`

I want to get everything between `' '` but from first to last occurrence.

I have tried to search my string by `/.*('.*').*/` but only `'fdsfdsf'` was taken, how to turn on greedy or something like that?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@result = $subject =~ m/'([^']*)'/g;
```

This will give you the strings enclosed in single quotes *within* each field in the string.

Of course, the quotes need to be balanced, and the regex match will be thrown off by escaped quotes in your string, so if those may occur, the pattern needs to be modified.

For example,

```
m/'((?:\\.|[^'])*)'/
```

would work if quotes can be escaped with backlashes.

Comment: Saying that the pattern would  need to be modified for escaped quotes is what I would call **dramatic understatement**, @Tim.  Are you British? ☺

Comment: @tchrist: No (German), but I grew up on a diet of The Beatles, Douglas Adams, Oscar Wilde, and Monty Python.

Answer (score 3):

`*` is greedy (*? is the non-greedy version). The following regex works fine: `/'(.*)'/`.

Comment: I don't think so - it'll capture everything from the first `'` to the last `'`.

Comment: @Tim, isn't that what was asked for?

Comment: @Tim: Which is literally what the OP asked for.

Comment: You're right. I guess I misinterpreted him (thinking that by first and last occurence he meant each string inside quotes, which would have made sense, at least to me).

Answer (score 3):

I am going to go out on a limb and assume that you want to actually get each everything between single quotes *within* each comma-separated field.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $foo = "'fdsfdsf', 'fsdfdsfdsfdsfds fdsf sdfd f sfs', 'fsdfsdfsd f' fdfsdfdsfdsfsf";

my @fields = map /'([^']*)'/, split ', ', $foo;

use YAML;
print Dump \@fields;
```

Output:

```
---
- fdsfdsf
- fsdfdsfdsfdsfds fdsf sdfd f sfs
- fsdfsdfsd f
```

Answer (score 0):

Below seems to be working as well. Please check:

```
@res = $str =~ m/'([A-Z|a-z| ]*)'*/g;
```